# Not able to apply Kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

what is wrong with the following YAML file? I am getting error when I apply it

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl apply -f codingjediweb-nodes.yaml
error: error validating "codingjediweb-nodes.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template): unknown field "volumes" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodTemplateSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

The file is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codingjediweb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: codingjediweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: codingjediweb
    spec:
    volumes:
    - name: shared-logs
      emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: codingjediweb
        image: docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:06072020
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        env:
        - name: db.cassandraUri
          value: cassandra://xx.tt.191.eee:9042
        - name: db.password
          value: 9vcvdvcs
        - name: db.keyspaceName
          value: something
        - name: db.username
          value: superuser
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      - name: logging
        image: busybox
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
          command: ["tail -f /codingjediweb-1.0/logs/"]
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the whole file, so I can only guess line 31 is the value for Cassandra URL. Double-quote it, it contains a ":".

Comment: sorry that space wasmy mistake when copying the file here. The actual value is an ip address.

Comment: added the whole file. Sorry missed that earlier

Comment: sorry, updated the question again.I rearranged the code and got  a new error

Comment: @ManuChadha, most probably an indentation issue.

Comment: it was. Thanks. It was my first time working in YAML so didn't know that indentation is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already mentioned you need to keep an eye on [indentations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm).

> - You should remember the following rules while working with indentation in `YAML:Flow` blocks must be intended with at least some
>   spaces with surrounding current block level.
> - Flow content of YAML spans multiple lines. The beginning of flow content begins with `{` or `[`.
> - Block list items include same indentation as the surrounding block level because `-` is considered as a part of indentation.

Example:

```
a:
   b:
      - c
      -  d
      - e
f:
      "ghi"
```

Usually in Kubernetes **two spaces** are being used as an indentation. Remember however, never to use tab for that.

The spec for that topic can be found [here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534).

And of course validation errors are useful to find the exact line where the issue is.

This is a community wiki answer aimed to explain this topic in more detail. Feel free to expand on that.

Answer (score 0):

This one is indented incorrectly.

```
 - name: logging
   image: busybox
   volumeMounts:
   - name: shared-logs
     mountPath: /codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
```